# Snap Box to Grid

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a small application where a user can take a Box and arrange it on a Pallet. I've managed to get it working using a 50x100 Box and making it snap to a grid by rounding the mouse position to the closest 50 value.

[image: Nice ratio Box]

The problem is that when I use an odd sized Box, e.g. 50x110, the boxes will overlap or have gaps, since I am forcing them to move to the closest 50 value. If I increase this value I get gaps between the boxes and if I make it too small, it becomes hard for a user to align the boxes so there is no gap between them

[image: Overlapping Box]

[image: Large Gap but looks okay]

I was wondering if anyone had anyway to approach this problem of getting the boxes to snap/align themselves with each other regardless of the size and ratio?

Here is part of the code that generates and places the buttons onto the pallet, explanation of the missing functions at the bottom

```
int package_width = 60;
    int package_height = 100;
    int snap_size = 50; //snap everything into 5 pixel limits
    int count = 0;
    int pallet_width = 400;
    int pallet_height = 400;

    JButton package_left = new JButton("<");
    package_left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Selector.selected = "<";
        }
    });

    JPanel pallet = new JPanel();
    pallet.setLayout(null);
    pallet.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            if(Selector.selected != "" && Selector.selected != null) {
                Point position = e.getPoint();

                JButton pack = new JButton(Selector.selected + Selector.count);

                int x_pos = -1;
                int y_pos = -1;
                int pack_height = -1;
                int pack_width = -1;
                if(Selector.selected == "<" || Selector.selected == ">") {
                    pack_width = package_height;
                    pack_height = package_width;
                }else {
                    pack_width = package_width;
                    pack_height = package_height;
                }
                pack.setSize(pack_width, pack_height);

                //snap using the height and width
                x_pos = (int)((int)(position.x-pack_width/2)/(pack_width/2))*pack_width/2;
                y_pos = (int)((int)(position.y-pack_height/2)/(pack_height/2))*pack_height/2;
                pack.setLocation(x_pos, y_pos);

                if(collision(pack.getLocation(), snap_size)) {
                    x_pos = -1;
                    y_pos = -1;
                }

                //If the position failed to set, its overlapping
                if (x_pos != -1 && y_pos != -1) {

                    Selector.point_list.add(pack.getLocation());
                    if(Selector.selected == "<" || Selector.selected == ">") {
                        Selector.point_list.add(new Point(pack.getLocation().x+snap_size, pack.getLocation().y));
                    }else{
                        Selector.point_list.add(new Point(pack.getLocation().x, pack.getLocation().y+snap_size));
                    }
                    pallet.add(pack);
                    main_page.repaint();

                    Selector.selected = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Collision Function

```
    public static boolean collision(Point pack, int snap_size) {
    Iterator<Point> it = Selector.point_list.iterator();
    Point next;
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        next = it.next();
        if(pack.x == next.x && pack.y == next.y) {
            return true;
        }
        if(Selector.selected == "<" || Selector.selected == ">") {              
            if(pack.x+snap_size == next.x && pack.y == next.y) {
                return true;
            }
        }else {
            if(pack.x == next.x && pack.y+snap_size == next.y) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The class `Selector` holds 2 static variables. One is the `point_list` which holds a list of all the points that have a button in them already. The other is `selected` which is used to determine the orientation of the button based on if the first button pressed has ^,v,< or > on it.

Comment: I guess you are using absolute layout. To avoid guesswork please post [mcve]

Comment: `If I increase this value` - well you need to "decrease" this value to say "10" (or even 5 as the comment in your code states) to give the user more flexibility to position the components.